# Acceptability of the conjunction 'that' after the noun 'statement'

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

I am not sure whether you use 'that' as a conjunction after the noun 'statement'.

> The *statement* [that] A is more than B is false.
>
> I do not agree with *the statement* [that] John often shirks the work. This is a slander.

Are they grammatical?

Comment: "shirks work" is the usual collocation. See ngram `(shirks the work),(shirks work)`.

Comment: *That* in *The statement that A is more than B is false* is out of place. It should be *That the statement A is more than B is false*. It,s fine without *that*, though.

Comment: @Damkerng T: When leading with "That", we wouldn't say "the statement": *That A is more than B is false.*

Comment: "The sentence A is good" is unidiomatic because "A" there is a determiner. Idiomatic: "Sentence A is good."

Comment: In the original post, "A" and "B" were variables: "The statement 'A is more than B' is false."

Comment: I am getting lost in your example. Here's a simpler analogue of what I'm saying: *That the statement "The sky is blue" is true* is a sentence-fragment.  It becomes a sentence in this way: *That the sky is blue is true.*

Comment: Or in this way: *The statement 'The sky is blue' is true.*

Comment: I've removed my discussion with TRomano because it's not really relevant to the OP's question. (In case you might want to know what it was all about, it's basically *(That) (the) statement (that) A is more than B is false* which I misread the OP's intention. It could be confusing indeed, if you tried to think of all the possibilities, with A and B as variables and A and B as stand-ins for some real sentences.) I left my first comment up there to keep TRomano's comments relevant. Anyway, I'd like to thank TRomano again for his patience and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *that* is optional in constructs like these:

> We know more people buy red cars than pink cars.
> We know **that** more people buy red cars than pink cars.
>
> The graph shows the price of oil has declined steadily over the past three months.
> The graph shows **that** the price of oil has declined steadily over the past three months.
>
> Becky said she might be late.
> Becky said **that** she might be late.

In the example you provide, there's no need to include "with the statement", although the word *that* must be used if we leave it out:

> I don't agree that John shirks his work.
> I don't agree with the statement that John shirks his work.

If we include the *with the statement*, we can omit the *that*, but we should punctuate the sentence accordingly:

> I don't agree with the statement: "John shirks his work."

You could accomplish the same thing with italics rather than quotation marks:

> The statement *A is more than B* is false.

Whether or not I include a *that* in such sentences comes down to personal preference and readability. Sometimes the sentence will read too "choppy" with the *that* omitted, and sometimes the sentence will seem too wordy with the *that* included. It's a case-by-case judgment call.